# What is wrong with my validation attribute derived from RegularExpressionAttribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My attribute looks like this. To my mind, it is a `RegularExpressionAttribute`, but just automatically gets constructed with a fixed pattern and has a more user friendly `ErrorMessage` set.

```
public class NumericOnlyAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public NumericOnlyAttribute()
        : base(@"\d+")
    {
        ErrorMessage = "Field must only contain numbers";
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the error u r getting?

Answer (score 0):

Every thing is ok. However you have to register a custom *DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider* so that MVC could recognize you custom validation attribute.

Check you this article it should give you a tip how to make it work http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/493405/Validating-User-Input-Containing-HTML-tags-in-ASP